# os.system(cmd) call fails with redirection operator

Tags: python-3.x

My Python 3.7.1 script generates a fasta file called

> pRNA.sites.fasta

Within the same script, I call following system command:

```
cmd = "weblogo -A DNA < pRNA.sites.fasta > OUT.eps"
os.system(cmd)
print(cmd) #for debugging
```

I am getting the following error message and debugging message on the command line.

> Error: Please provide a multiple sequence alignment
>
> weblogo -A DNA < pRNA.sites.fasta > OUT.eps

"OUT.eps" file is generated but it's emtpy. On the other hand, if I run the following 'weblogo' command from the command line, It works just find. I get proper OUT.eps file.

```
$ weblogo -A DNA<pRNA.sites.fasta>OUT.eps
```

I am guessing my syntax for os.system call is wrong. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It turned out to be that I was not closing my file, "pRNA.sites.fasta" before I make system call that uses this file.